# How to move bones with IK?

Tags: rigging, bones, inverse-kinematics

[image]

Hi, does anyone know how I can move the end bone?

The bone only rotates or scales depending on the connected checkbox.

File here:

[image]

Comment: yes please share your file on wetransfer or https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a controller bone that will control your IK:

- Create a bone from the last one and deparent it with <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd>.
- Deactivate the *Deform* option of this bone so that this bone won't deform the mesh of your object when you'll parent it to the armature.
- Choose this new bone as the *Target* of your IK bone.
- Move the controller, the bones will follow.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. You saved my life.